# How can I move a class name among like elements by method of an event listener?

Tags: jquery

So below you can see two elements.  One active and one inactive.  There are 3 more tagged with inactive.  Nav is a pagination essentially.  I want to have one element tagged with active at a time with the right and left arrows triggering that class to move backwards and forwards through the group.

HTML example

```
<div
      class="testimonials__card testimonials__card--hidden testimonials__card--desktop-odd active"
    >
      <div class="testimonials__card-text">
        “I fell asleep hard and fast and stayed asleep for hours which is
        very unusual for me. Today I feel energized like I actually got a
        good night’s sleep! I definitely recommend 100%!”
      </div>
      <div class="testimonials__card-name">- Keah</div>
    </div>
    <div
      class="testimonials__card testimonials__card--c3o inactive testimonials__card--desktop-even"
    >
      <div class="testimonials__card-text">
        “I have tried multiple sleep-aids, and this is by far the most
        effective one! I highly recommend it.”
      </div>
      <div class="testimonials__card-name">- Kody</div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$('body').on('click', '#test-arrow-right', function () {
$('.testimonials__card').each(function (e) {
  if ($(this).is('.active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
  }
});
```

Tried

```
$(this).siblings(':first').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');

$(this).next().removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
```

Tried map and a few other methods.  Think its time I just asked even though I should know how to fix this.

Comment: `$('.testimonials__card.active').toggleClass('active inactive').next().toggleClass('active inactive')`?

Answer (score 0):

[`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) is your friend here. You don't need the `each` even, just keep calling `next()` from the currently-active element.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#test-arrow-right', function() {
  $('.testimonials__card.active').toggleClass('active inactive').next().toggleClass('active inactive');
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
.inactive { color: black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testimonials__card testimonials__card--hidden testimonials__card--desktop-odd active">
  <div class="testimonials__card-text">
    “I fell asleep hard and fast and stayed asleep for hours which is very unusual for me. Today I feel energized like I actually got a good night’s sleep! I definitely recommend 100%!”
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials__card-name">- Keah</div>
</div>
<div class="testimonials__card testimonials__card--c3o inactive testimonials__card--desktop-even">
  <div class="testimonials__card-text">
    “I have tried multiple sleep-aids, and this is by far the most effective one! I highly recommend it.”
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials__card-name">- Kody</div>
</div>
<button id="test-arrow-right">right</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the div has a class using `hasClass` method and then add or remove classes depending on this .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('body').on('click', '#test-arrow-right', function() {
  $('.testimonials__card').each(function(e) {
//chck with hasclass return true/false 
    var select_cond = $(this).hasClass('active')
    select_cond ? $(this).addClass('inactive').removeClass('active') : $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
  });
})
```

```css
.inactive {
  background-color: red;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test-arrow-right">Click</button>
<div class="testimonials__card testimonials__card--hidden testimonials__card--desktop-odd active">
  <div class="testimonials__card-text">
    “I fell asleep hard and fast and stayed asleep for hours which is very unusual for me. Today I feel energized like I actually got a good night’s sleep! I definitely recommend 100%!”
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials__card-name">- Keah</div>
</div>
<div class="testimonials__card testimonials__card--c3o inactive testimonials__card--desktop-even">
  <div class="testimonials__card-text">
    “I have tried multiple sleep-aids, and this is by far the most effective one! I highly recommend it.”
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials__card-name">- Kody</div>
</div>
<div class="testimonials__card testimonials__card--hidden testimonials__card--desktop-odd active">
  <div class="testimonials__card-text">
    “I fell asleep hard and fast and stayed asleep for hours which is very unusual for me. Today I feel energized like I actually got a good night’s sleep! I definitely recommend 100%!”
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials__card-name">- Keah</div>
</div>
<div class="testimonials__card testimonials__card--hidden testimonials__card--desktop-odd inactive">
  <div class="testimonials__card-text">
    “I fell asleep hard and fast and stayed asleep for hours which is very unusual for me. Today I feel energized like I actually got a good night’s sleep! I definitely recommend 100%!”
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials__card-name">- Keah</div>
</div>
```